# How to decorate the service provider?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I want to add property injection to the existing ServiceProvider in a asp.net core application. I was thinking of adapting and decorating the default service provider in my custom IServiceProvider implementation. This custom service provider is then made available with a custom IServiceProviderFactory implementation like so:

```
public class MyCustomServiceProvider : IServiceProvider, ISupportRequiredService, IServiceProviderIsService
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider serviceProvider;

    public MyCustomServiceProvider(IServiceCollection containerBuilder, ServiceProviderOptions options) =>
        serviceProvider = containerBuilder.BuildServiceProvider(options);

    public object GetRequiredService(Type serviceType) =>
        // TODO: decoration
        serviceProvider.GetRequiredService(serviceType);

    public object? GetService(Type serviceType) =>
        // TODO: decoration
        serviceProvider.GetService(serviceType);

    public bool IsService(Type serviceType) =>
        serviceProvider.GetService(serviceType) is not null;
}

public class MyCustomServiceProviderFactory : IServiceProviderFactory<IServiceCollection>
{
    public IServiceCollection CreateBuilder(IServiceCollection services) => services;

    public IServiceProvider CreateServiceProvider(IServiceCollection containerBuilder) =>
        new MyCustomServiceProvider(containerBuilder, new());
}
```

In my Program.cs file I then register this custom service provider factory like so:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Host.UseServiceProviderFactory(new MyCustomServiceProviderFactory());

// ...
```

However, this approach does only partially work. Services will actually get resolved through the custom service provider. However, If I resolve the IServiceProvider I get Microsoft's internal service provider (ServiceProviderEngineScope):

```
var app = builder.Build();

var serviceProvider = app.Services.GetRequiredService<IServiceProvider>();

Debug.Assert(serviceProvider is MyCustomServiceProvider); // Fails
```

My question therefore is how can I properly create a thin wrapper around the existing service provider in asp.net core to decorate its GetService and GetRequiredService method (in this case injecting properties of the returned service)?

Because my project uses the IServiceProvider internally for some special scenario I require the IServiceProvider dependency to also resolve to my customer service provider. My assumption is that it has to do with using the IServiceCollection to build the actual service provider. I did look into Autofac's implementation and they do basically the same except they use their own internal service provider and don't use the one created with IServiceCollection.BuildServiceProvider.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand correctly, but can't you do `If (serviceType == typeof(IServiceProvider) ) return this;`?

Comment: @Silvermind This line is just to show that the serviceProvider is not an instance of MyCustomServiceProvider.

Comment: No, I mean for you to put the if statement inside your custom service provider. So if someone requests `IServiceProvider` from your provider, you return yours.

Comment: Your solution will only work for services directly resolved by the service provider, not by such service's dependencies. Say for instance you want to apply property injection to `MyRepository`, but that class is injected into an `MyService`, which is injected into a `MyController`. That `MyRepository won't get intercepted, likely only `MyController`.

Answer (score 1):

notice these lines:

```
private readonly IServiceProvider serviceProvider;

public MyCustomServiceProvider(IServiceCollection containerBuilder, ServiceProviderOptions options) =>
    serviceProvider = containerBuilder.BuildServiceProvider(options);
```

It would return an instance of ServiceProvider instead of your Custom Service Provider

[image]

Since you've changed nothing inside `GetService` method ,it would totally follow the behavior of `ServiceProvider.GetService` method,return  the default ServiceProvider to you whenyou call `GetRequiredService<IServiceProvider>()`

> they use their own internal service provider and don't use the one
> created with IServiceCollection.BuildServiceProvider.

So what have you tried follow the codes?and what's the problem you're facing now?

Comment: Turns out what I had in mind does indeed not work due to what you mentioned. Their internal service provider has a hard dependency on itself which can't be replaced. Seems to be a design issue with Microsofts ServiceProvider that is not open for extension.